# Magento not saving backend changes

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, installation

I've just install Magento on a new website. On backend, when I try to edit / change something on Catalog, CMS, System... anything, and click on Save, it does not save the changes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: edit means how you did that, editing phtml file or something else.i cant get you?

Comment: I mean in the backend. CMS > Pages, when I edit a page, it doesn't save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean in the admin make sure all of your html tags are closed properly otherwise they won't save.  I find it easier to make all my edits in sublime text then do a simple copy and paste into the page.

Comment: I mean in the backend. CMS > Pages, when I edit a page, it doesn't save.

Comment: Make sure your tags are closed. I prefer disabling wysiwyg from system -> config. You could also check to see if your IP is listed under system - config -developer - Allowed IPs. You can set the IP changes come from.

Comment: It's not saving anything. I tried to make those changes and it did not save.

Comment: Can you post what you're trying to save?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't save anything on backend. Not on Catalog, CMS, System, nothing.

Comment: Go to system -> Configuration -> Developer(bottom sidebar)-> then scroll back up and you'll see Allowed IPs.  Clear out any IP in that field. If the IPs youre coming from isn't in there it wont let you make changes in the backend. Clear it out and hit save.  Later you can put your own IP in there so that only people from that address can make edits.

Comment: I've tried that, but as I said backend wasn't saving anything. I figured it out tho, just renamed .htaccess.sample to .htaccess and now it's working.